# Spring Data Rest Not Mapped

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am trying to use spring data rest. I have included its dependency in pom and defined following bean but no mapping is being created for repos. From where do I began to look for problem?

```
@Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer(){

        return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config){
                config.setBasePath("/api");
            }
        };
    }
```

following is pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <hibernate.core.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.core.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <jackson-version>2.7.5</jackson-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.2</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <maven-war-plugin-version>2.4</maven-war-plugin-version>
        <source-jdk>1.8</source-jdk>
        <target-jdk>1.8</target-jdk>
        <war-source-directory>src/main/webapp</war-source-directory>
        <war-name>dmapp</war-name>
        <final-name>dmapp</final-name>
  </properties> 

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--    SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!--  Javax Transactions -->    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>  
    </dependency>




    <!-- POSTGRESQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Joda-Time -->       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency> -->

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${source-jdk}</source>
                <target>${target-jdk}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${war-source-directory}</warSourceDirectory>
                <warName>${war-name}</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${final-name}</finalName>
  </build>
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.pdma.dmapp.configuration;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pdma.dmapp")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver(){
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webResources/**").addResourceLocations("/webResources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
    }
}
```

PersistenceContext.java

```
package com.pdma.dmapp.configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:db.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.pdma.dmapp.module")
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String [] {"com.pdma.dmapp.module"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            DataSource dataSource,
            Environment env){

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = 
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String [] {"com.pdma.dmapp.module"});

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;

    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(  environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(              environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(         environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(         environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties(){

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",     environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql",    environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql",  environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTXManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){

        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);    
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTXManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }


    /*  Same Bean Created as above because CrudRepository Methods are annotated with @Transactional
     *  So they require a bean named transactionManager*/

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer(){

        return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter(){

            @Override
            public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config){
                config.setBasePath("/api");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.pdma.dmapp.configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("Admin")
        .password("admin123")
        .roles("Admin");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login","/webResources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('Admin')")
            .and().formLogin()
                  .loginPage("/login")
                  .usernameParameter("username")
                  .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().csrf()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");

        http.sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl("/login.html");
    }
}
```

AppInitializer.java

```
package com.pdma.dmapp.configuration;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    private static final String LOCATION = "D:/uploads/";
    private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024*1024*200;
    private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024*1024*200;
    private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0;

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class [] {AppConfig.class, PersistenceContext.class, SecurityConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String [] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration){
        registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
    }

    private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement(){
        MultipartConfigElement element = new MultipartConfigElement(LOCATION,
                                                                    MAX_FILE_SIZE,
                                                                    MAX_REQUEST_SIZE,
                                                                    FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
        return element;
    }


     @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.pdma.dmapp.module.surveys.repo;

@Transactional("jpaTXManager")
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = true)
public interface SurveyorRepo extends CrudRepository<Surveyor, Integer> {

    Surveyor findByDeviceImeiNo1OrDeviceImeiNo2(String deviceImeiNo1, String deviceImeiNo2);
    List<Surveyor> findByDistrictDistrictId(Integer districtId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to configure `Sprint Data REST` in the following way:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRepositoryRestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
            @Override
            public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config){
                config.setBasePath("/api");
            }
...
}
```

Also, make sure your repository beans are available in `Spring` context and annotate them with `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation.

**EDIT:** I think the main problem is how you mix MVC with Spring Data REST. Use `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` instead of `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`. You can find the detailed guide on how to setup both in official guides [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.adding-sdr-to-spring-mvc-app) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/install-chapter.html).

**UPDATE:** With newer version of `Spring Data REST` the base path is set in different way:

```
@Configuration
public class RestDataConfig  extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public BaseUri baseUri() {
        config().setBasePath("/api");
        return new BaseUri(config().getBaseUri());
    }
}
```

Comment: did this and still not working. my configuration file is located in com.pdma.dmapp.configuration. while I am specifying com.pdma.dmapp as base package to scan.

Comment: should work that way but still it's always better to put config in base package, in your case com.pdma.dmapp. also, please share all Spring configurations you have and repositories code.

Comment: configuration files added.

Comment: I think the main problem is how you mix MVC with Spring Data REST. You need to use `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`. Check my updated answer.

Comment: adding @Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class) in PersistenceContext.java solved the problem. Now how to configure basepath ?

Comment: Use a` CustomRepositoryRestConfiguration` where you configure the base bath as in the answer and use it in Import instead of `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`

Comment: which method to override in CustomRepositoryMvcConfiguration? the mentioned method "configureRepositoryRestConfiguration" doesnt exist

Comment: Seems that it was removed with a new version of `Spring Data REST`. Try to provide a BaseUri bean by overriding baseUri() method. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.html#baseUri--

Comment: done as follows:

Configuration
Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class RestDataConfig  extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

 Override
 Bean
 public BaseUri baseUri() {
  config().setBasePath("/api");
  return new BaseUri(config().getBaseUri());
 }
}

Comment: Use `Import(RestDataConfig.class)` and place it over `AppConfig`. This should work. And please accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Worth mentioning is the fact that in Spring Data REST 3.+ API of RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration changed and in case people seeking the answer for versions 3+ could:

1. @Import RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration

   ```
   @Import( ...,
       RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class,
       ...)
   public class YourConfig { //snip }
   ```
2. Register a RepositoryRestConfigurer @Bean by extending RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter and overriding basePath

   ```
   @Bean
   public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {
       return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config){
               // snip
               config.setBasePath("/data");
               // snip               

   }
   ```

Worth noting is the fact that the same approach can be used to expose IDs for entities and managing other features RepositoryRestConfigurer is responsible for.